# Array not displaying both of its values

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, prepend

I'm trying to prepend a div for every element that I have in an array. 
I currently have *elem1* and *elem2* stored in the *appendedElements* array.
Using a for loop, I am looping through the array and attempting to display two divs, one with "elem1" as the text, and the other with "elem2".

Currently what is happening is that it is correctly prepending the number of divs that it should but it displaying elem2 twice!

```
var appendedElements = ["elem1","elem2"];

         for(var x in appendedElements) {
            var appendedFirst = '<div class="media"><p>'+ appendedElements[x] +'</p></div>'
         }
         $.each(appendedElements,function() {
            $('.statusfeed').prepend(appendedFirst);
         });
```

Help me out here guys!

Comment: You rewrite the value of `appendedFirst` at each step of the loop. Overall, the code doesn't have much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you're trying to accomplish because it's not very clear.

```
var appendedElements = ["elem1","elem2"];
 $.each(appendedElements, function(i, v) {
    var addThis = '<div class="media"><p>'+ v +'</p></div>'
    $('.statusfeed').prepend(addThis);
 });
```

Comment: yeah, looks like I didn't need that for loop after all, that was just confusing me! Thank you.